# How to switch wifi channel without dropping connection?

Tags: linux, embedded, wifi

We are developing small internet connected device that connects via wifi and does some work. It is controlled via mobile app.

For configuration purposes we use wi-fi module that can work in both STA + AP modes simultaneously via two interfaces wlan0 and wlan1. One of the interfaces works in Master mode. Phone connects to the device via wlan1 and sends command for the device to connect to another network and waits for result. Device in turn connects to another wi-fi network using wlan0 and notifies the phone if connection was successful or not.

But there is one issue. Both interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) must work on the same channel as we have single hardware module. This causes channel of wlan1 to change in order to match of channel for wlan0.

Here comes the problem. When channel changes phone looses connection with the device. **Is there a way to change wi-fi channel but keep connection between the device and mobile phone?**

Our wi-fi module is rtl8723bu.
Linux 3.4.103.
Wifi daemons: hostapd v0.8.x_rtw_r7475.20130812_beta, wpa_supplicant v2.3.

**UPDATE**
Here is more clearly description what is going on on device.

Let's assume that the phone already connected to Device wlan1 interface with essid DeviceAp which is on channel 1. We have a Router with essid RouterAp which is on channel 6. Device interface wlan0 is not configured and not running. 
(Step1 on image below).

Then the phone sends a request to the device to connect to RouterAp.
(Step2 on image below).

When wlan0 starts connecting to RouterAp it changes working channel. Because WiFi module can work only on one channel. The channel of wlan1  also changes  (maybe in hard way). Therefore Phone lost DeviceAp and starts roaming. 
(Step3 on image below).

*SO the update question is:*

**Is there a way to tell the Phone (or other device) about network change? Or perhaps increase the likelihood that the phone is connected back to DeviceAP.**

This behavior is very similar to the process of setting up Google Chromecast. 
Chromecast also has two wireless interfaces and change the channel, but the Phone does not lose connection with it.

Image:
http://postimg.org/image/soh78vd17/

Comment: [Linux bonding driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation#Linux_bonding_driver) and many other solutions... Create pty and do ppp and bridge traffic in user-space, etc.

Comment: @artless noise:
Could you please elaborate on this? I may be wrong, but as I understand wi-fi channel change is a hard drop for all clients and this causes iPhone to switch to other known hot spot.

Comment: Your question was not clear that this is what you want.  You can use channel roaming if the iPhone supports it.  Your AP will have two BSSID for the different channels, with the same SSID.

Comment: It's an old post but I'll answer anyway.  I'm not sure what chrome cast is doing.  Maybe it scans the networks, finds the higher power RSSI and decides to spawn its AP with that channel so when you connect as client it won't have to change channels.  If the device is android, you can issue a scan and reconnect automatically.